# Changes in the MobileFirst project is not reflect in the application

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

When I made any changes (JS, HTML, or even app version) in the MobileFirst project, then rebuild and redeploy the app to device or simulator/emulator, nothing appears to change in the application.  If I uninstall the app from the device and redeploy the app, then the changes are visible in the app.  This is not related to direct update. This only happens with iOS environment.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the Run Script is missing in my Xcode project so the buildtime.sh file was never executed.  As a result, buildtime property was not updated.  With the same buildtime, nothing was updated in the app.

Solution:
In Xcode, select your project and open the Build Phase tab.  Click on the + icon on the top left to Add a New Build Phase. Select the new Run Script Phase and copy/paste the following to the new script:

```
script_file="buildtime.sh"

echo "Running a custom build phase script: $script_file"
unsecure_project_path=${PROJECT_DIR}
secure_project_path="${unsecure_project_path// /\ }"
eval ${secure_project_path}/${script_file}
scriptExitStatus=$?
echo "DONE with script: ${script_file} (exitStatus=${scriptExitStatus})\n\n"
exit "${scriptExitStatus}"
```

The Run Script should look like this:
[image]